# Resource interpreted as font but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: css, fonts

```
@font-face {
    font-family:kai;
    src: url(fonts/kai.ttf);
}

body {
    font-family: kai, georgia, tahoma,verdana,serif;        
}
```

I checked with this web site http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php  [image]

Not quite sure it won't use this font?
How can I get it to use this particular font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://serverfault.com/questions/186965/how-can-i-make-nginx-support-font-face-formats-and-allow-access-control-allow-or

COnfigure your nginx like the above.

Comment: If you do not have rights then I'm afraid you can't do anything about it.